# Change xfce4-power-manager option from terminal

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, xfce, xfce4-power-manager

I'd like to change a `xfce4-power-manager` setting (what to do when laptop lid is closed on AC) via the terminal so that I can assign a keyboard shortcut to do it.

[image]

Is there a way how to do it? Similar to `dconf-editor set` for gnome..

## EDIT

ok, I found the file at `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-power-manager.xml`. But changing it doesn't do anything. How do I reload `xfce4-power-manager`? I tried `xfce4-power-manager --restart` but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it, have to use `xfconf-query` to get/set values.

To get the value:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/lid-action-on-ac
```

To set the value:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/lid-action-on-ac -s 1
```

`-c` specify channel, `-p` is for property within that channel, `-s` is for setting value, `1` for suspend, `0` for do nothing.

Comment: I see "0" when I have "Switch off display" selected  - but there is no open to "Do nothing".

Comment: at least for alterating `lock-screen-suspend-hibernate` neither sending HUP to xfce4-power-manager nor running it well --restart seems to reliably make the change take effect.